# The view blog.views.post_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm having some problems with getting my Django based blog to display. When running the Django web server in debug mode I'm getting the following error message:

> The view blog.views.post_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead (Django)

It only happens when I'm trying to access my blog application. Other templates are rendering fine. I would be very much grateful for your assistance. Here's the stack trace below:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://Some_URL

Django Version: 2.0.4
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'blog',
 'markdown',
 'taggit']
 Installed Middleware:
 ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

 Traceback:

 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
 packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
   139.                 "returned None instead." % 
(callback.__module__, view_name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: The view blog.views.post_list didn't return an 
HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Here's a partial extract from my views.py file of the definition which seems to be causing the problem:

```
def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None
    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
         posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'blog.html', {'page': page, 'posts': posts, 'tag': tag})
```

Comment: The code as posted here would not cause this error. Are you sure the indentation is exactly as you have it? For example, could the final `return render(..)` call be inside the except block? Or is everything inside the `if tag_slug` block?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniel for your answer, but the problem didn't have anything to do with indentation or with tag_slug section. It turns out that there was an issue with one of the REGEX filters configuration in the url.py file. It wasn't obvious, because I was following a guide in a book and there was a typo.